# How to redirect to another action method after returning a view in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, web-applications

I have an action method `Index()`

```
Function Index(searchTerm As String) As ActionResult
       'some logic here
        Return View(userlistview)
End Function
```

and another one: `ListAllUsers()`

```
Function ListAllUsers() As ActionResult
    Dim userlist As List(Of tblUsers)
    ' some logic here
    'Return View("Index", userlistview)
End Function
```

i am calling action method `ListAllUsers()` from `Index` view in action link, However i have an issue after `ListAllUsers()` returned a view, url is `.../Account/ListAllUsers`, but i want it to be `.../Account/Index` .

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you want to use `RedirectToAction` or not? The URL displayed in address bar is exactly same as the action method you're calling unless it redirects to another action.

Comment: yes. i want to use if it solves my issue, i tied `RedirectToAction` but i also want  to return a view with model.

Comment: You can setting up `Index` action method, pull `List(Of tblUsers)` to a `TempData` or `Session` inside `ListAllUsers` action, then read the `TempData` or `SessionKey` which contains the list on `Index` action and return it to view page.

Comment: Thank you, but how do i check that whether the call to index is from view or from  `ListAllUsers` action method, so that i will do the logic inside `index` by checking if is from a redirect something and if not another

Comment: You can check from the `TempData` or `Session` variable that carries `List(Of tblUsers)` instance. If it's null or empty list, the request may be from somewhere else. But if it contains `List(Of tblUsers)` with certain records, there you can know it comes from `ListAllUsers` redirection.

Comment: thank you very much it helps, answer it please.